# Move data from one table to another

Tags: mysql, insert, move, sql-delete

This question seems to be answered multiple times. However none match the criteria I need.

Is it possible to select (and insert them in another table) and delete rows from the original table in Mysql without running the selected criteria twice?

For example I could do this:

```
INSERT INTO main (SELECT * FROM temp WHERE age > 30)
DELETE FROM cache WHERE age > 30
```

However with a very complex and long running query the 'match part' of the query would be executed twice, whilst I think that there should be a solution to delete the selected items, since you have fetched them already anyways.

My question, is this possible, and if so. How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't do that.

You should use a transaction if you are worried about the integrity of your tables in between the job.

Comment: My main concern was performance. The time for the query to execute is quite long. And having to execute it twice makes it even longer.

Comment: Well, if it is **trul** something really complicated, (as in something more complex than your initial example), then make sure that you have an index on which ever column you want to delete by, and then break up your query into three queries. Three fast queries, could be softer than two draining ones. Just make sure you are indexing correctly and all should be fine.