# Oracle sequence in a queue table

Tags: oracle, queue, sequence

So I have a table called `rentalqueue(queue_id,customer_id,movie_title,etc.)` I also have a sequence on the `queue_id` as such:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE rentalqueue_seq
  MINVALUE     100
  MAXVALUE     300
  START WITH   100
  INCREMENT BY 1
  NOCACHE;
```

Lets say I insert several movie titles into `rentalqueue` for a given customer from a movie table. How can I implement a trigger(assumption), so that I can designate the very last movie added in the queue? Assume I add 5 movies over lets say a couple days, each with a different `timestamp`.

Comment: What do you mean by "designate the very last movie"?

Comment: the very last movie added to the rentalqueue, meaning from a time standpoint, the most recent.

Comment: @user3015045 What do you mean by _designate_?

Comment: select? I want to select that row/queue_id in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you modify your sequence so that the `maxvalue` is something like 99999999. You can select the last movie added for a customer like this:

```
select *
from (
  select *
  from   rentalqueue
  where  customer_id = :p_customer_id
  order by queue_id desc)
where rownum = 1
```

Or, if you have a `date_added` field (or something similar), like this:

```
select *
from (
  select *
  from   rentalqueue
  where  customer_id = :p_customer_id
  order by date_added desc)
where rownum = 1
```

Comment: I will try that and let you know. I assume rownum is something built in that acts like a timestamp of some sort?

Comment: Is it possible to move contents of one table to another table? Meaning, if I wanted to move rows from Table A into Table B, based on lets say an attribute customer_ID. So in essence, moving data into a history table.

Comment: That's a totally different question. But yes, it is possible. You insert the rows into the other table and delete them from the original one.

Comment: I know that much, but is there an automated way of doing it, or it has to be done manually/individually?

Comment: You can write a procedure and schedule a job that does that automatically every hour/day/etc.

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545512/move-data-from-one-table-to-another?rq=1

Comment: Thanks Alen the first part makes sense if it works, will try it.